# ASP.NET Core and dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Is there a proper way to declare my services, than that :

```
services.AddTransient<ILogger>(provider => new Logger(Configuration["..."]));
services.AddTransient<ICatalogService>(provider => new CatalogService(Configuration["..."], new Logger(Configuration["..."])));
```

I would like to avoid declaring "new Logger" 2 times.

Edit : The catalog service take a string in the constructor too.

```
public CatalogService(ILogger logger, string path)
{
}
```

and

```
public Logger(string value)
{
}
```

Comment: looks great, don't know this !

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
services.AddTransient<ILogger>(provider => new Logger(Configuration["..."]))
services.AddTransient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>();
```

In `CatalogService` class there will be something like this:

```
public class CatalogService(ILogger logger) {
...
}
```

As you have already registered the implementation for ILogger, the IOC will automatically create an instance to use in your `CatalogService` class.

**EDIT**: Based in your edition, there's no need to inject a `new Configuration` every time. Just register the implementation for your `IConfiguration` and it will be injected automatically when needed. I haven't tested, but should be something like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
services.AddTransient<ILogger, Logger>()
services.AddTransient<ICatalogService, CatalogService>()
```

By the way, [this link](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/may/23/strongly-typed-configuration-settings-in-aspnet-core) could help you.

Comment: sorry, my question was not enough precise. I added precsions

Comment: @Tim: Register your `Configuration` seperately.

Comment: you mean with IOptions pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `IOption<T>` pattern wherever possible, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects) for more information.

In case you can't use the `IOptions<T>` pattern (i.e. logger being defined in a 3rd party library or a legacy library which doesn't support this pattern), then you can resolve the logger in the factory method.

```
services.AddTransient<ILogger>(provider => new Logger(Configuration["..."]));
services.AddTransient<ICatalogService>(provider => new CatalogService(Configuration["..."], provider.GetService<ILogger>()));
```

This way the logger will be resolved from the previously configured configuration. This is the reason why the `provider` is passed into the factory method.